# String "N/A" is being recognized as zero in conditional formatting formula

Tags: excel, formatting

I currently have an excel spreadsheet that is using the following conditional formatting formula.

```
=OR($M$11<-5,$M$11<$C$7,$M$11<$H$7)
```

If the above statement is true, the cell turns green. The problem I am having is sometimes the cell H7 has "N/A" as a string (not the error #N/A) and treats the cell as zero. I am trying to re-write the conditional formatting formula so that if H7 is "N/A," the formula ignores the last inequality. Essentially, the formula would be stopping at the M11< C7 part.

Would anyone know how to adjust this formula to fix the problem I mentioned above? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try adding a nested `AND` condition, which applies the inequality only when `H7` does not equal `N/A`:

```
=OR($M$11 < -5, $M$11 < $C$7, AND($H$7 <> "N/A", $M$11 < $H$7))
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that H7 is a number.

```
=OR($M$11<-5, $M$11<$C$7, AND(ISNUMBER($H$7), $M$11<$H$7))
```

Text is always considered *greater than* a number.